# « entraîneur », « s'entraîner » dans le contexte d'un logiciel éducatif

Tags: sens, traduction, terminologie

En allemand, il est complètement normal d'utiliser des expressions comme « Vokabel*trainer* », « Grammatik*trainer* », etc. pour désigner un certain type de logiciel qui propose des exercices interactifs (souvent sous forme de drill-and-practice).

La maison d'édition PONS utilise apparemment l'expression « *entraîneur* de vocabulaire » pour traduire « Vokabel*trainer* » : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nomtek&hl=fr

Curieusement, des recherches Google pour les mots « entraîneur » et « s'entraîner » me donnent très peu de résultats qui concernent le contexte de l'e-learning...

- Est-ce que l'usage du nom « entraîneur » vous semble bizarre dans ce contexte ? Est-ce qu'il existe une meilleure expression pour désigner un tel
  logiciel ?
- Est-ce que le verbe pronominal « s'entraîner » s'utilise dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Généralement, le mot « [entraîneur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entraineur) » est presque exclusivement associé à une *personne* dans le contexte *sportif*. Alors, à mon avis, un « entraîneur de vocabulaire », hors contexte du logiciel dont on parle, ce serait une personne préparant d'autres personnes à un concours portant sur le vocabulaire...<sup>1</sup>

Au *GDT*, on retrouve à l'entrée [*didacticiel*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198732) (extraits) :

> *Définition*
>  
>   Logiciel spécialisé dans l'enseignement d'une discipline, d'une
>   méthode ou de certaines connaissances.
>
> *Termes privilégiés*
>   didacticiel   n. m.  
>  
>    - <sub>normalisé par l'Office québécois de la langue
>   française (janvier 1986)</sub>
>  logiciel éducatif   n. m.
>  logiciel
>   d'enseignement   n. m.
>  logiciel d'apprentissage   n. m.
>   logiciel pédagogique   n. m.
>  apprenticiel   n. m.
>   - <sub>Le terme *apprenticiel* est un synonyme peu répandu de *didacticiel*.</sub>
>
> [ *Le grand dictionnaire terminologique* (GDT) ]

Le même genre d'entrée dans [*FranceTerme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=didacticiel&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) comporte une note:

> 1. Un logiciel éducatif peut comporter un module de contrôle des connaissances acquises par l'utilisateur.
>
> [ *FranceTerme - termes recommandés au Journal officiel de la République française.*]

---

Par ailleurs, « [entraîner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entrainer) » ne pose aucun problème en contexte:

> Former, soumettre quelqu'un à une activité physique ou intellectuelle
>   de manière à créer une aptitude ou une habitude.

Dans sa forme pronominale, on peut donc imaginer pouvoir *s'entraîner au vocabulaire* français (voir aussi peut-être [*s'exercer à*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exercer); mais prendre garde à [*se pratiquer*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18046911)). On peut donc penser au *didacticiel d'[entraînement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entra%C3%AEnement) au vocabulaire*; comme composante, on peut référer au *module*. Plusieurs combinaisons sont ainsi possibles, mais je ne saurais dire laquelle est la meilleure.

---

Il y avait peut-être des contraintes (longueur) à l'élaboration des menus du site web de *PONS*. On peut aussi avoir opté à dessein pour l'idée du sport ou de la compétition, vu leur popularité. Ou, plus simplement, on se sera fié à [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto/fr/Vokabeltrainer). Oui, pour moi c'est bizarre ici, et je crois que c'est inadéquat; reste qu'en contexte c'est parfaitement compréhensible, à mon avis.

---

<sub>1. Dans le domaine de l'aide à la formation en *aéronautique*, il semble qu'on ait déjà utilisé « entraîneur » ([*system trainer*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&srchtxt=entraineur&i=1&index=frt&sg_kp=985905&fchrcrdnm=13#zz13), [*rear crew trainer*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=trainer&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0)). Ailleurs, on a préféré « d'entraînement » ([*appareil d'entraînement*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19499978), [*avion d'entraînement*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19467213), c'est-à-dire essentiellement un *simulateur*). On retrouve aussi, dans la direction opposée pourrait-on dire, le [*système d'apprentissage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8370729) dans un contexte où c'est l'utilisateur qui entraîne un système à reconnaître son écriture, par exemple; je le mentionne pour qu'on l'évite.</sub>